# How to put Meta Title Page

Tags: meta

i am trying to figure out the way to put my own Title on pages. I cannot find the field " meta tile"

I have browsed and it seems i have to put the code inside Design/Layout Update XML.
I found following code:

Your Module Page Title

Is " Your Module Page Title " should be the page title?

Hi hope hear from you soon
P.

Comment: is that cms page ? or module page? any Idea. or share url I will check and update you

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: ok. How can i set up Meta title for pages? I can see Keywords and meta description but i cannot find Meta title.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you like to set custom `<title>` in the CMS Pages. To do this you have to add new column in the database to store this info. The table is **cms_page**. Please add column **meta_title** similar to the **title** column. Then in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Meta.php` -> `protected function _prepareForm()` add this:

```
$fieldset->addField('meta_title', 'text', array(
    'name' => 'meta_title',
    'label' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Title'),
    'title' => Mage::helper('cms')->__('Meta Title'),
    'disabled'  => $isElementDisabled
));
```

before `$fieldset->addField('meta_keywords'`. This way a new field Meta Title will be added in the `admin panel -> CMS -> Pages -> tab Meta Data`. To display it in `<title>` in `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Block/Page.php` -> `protected function _prepareLayout()` replace this:

```
$head->setTitle($page->getTitle());
```

with this:

```
$head->setTitle($page->getMetaTitle() ? $page->getMetaTitle() : $page->getTitle());
```

So if there is filled Meta Title - it will be displayed otherwise the standard Title will be shown. That's it! Don't forget to flush the cache. And of course it's better to make an extension or at least copy the files in `app/code/local` not edit them directly.

Comment: And of course it's better to make an extension or at least copy the files in app/code/local not edit them directly? HOW?

Comment: If you don't have experience with Magento - it will be hard for you to create an extension. About copy the files to `app/code/local` - you just have to copy them with the full directory structure, i.e. copy `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Meta.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Meta.php` and so on. Please accept/rate my answer if it is helpful to you.

Comment: I think i have to study a little bit ;) Many thanks for the explanation.

Comment: This *nearly* works for me - field is added in the cms and shows value of meta_title field in db. The meta title is replaced in the cms also. Only thing is I can't update the field from the cms - it just doesn't change the db value. Cleared cache, logged out/in. I know magento has trouble with this sometimes.

Good answer though :)

Comment: EDIT - It works after an indeterminate amount of time. I tried everything but eventually it just started working. If I ever figure out exactly what triggers it to work then I'll update this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an xml update on the cms page 
**DESIGN >> Layout Update XML**

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle"><title>Your Page Title Here</title></action>
</reference>
```